# Nest js Downloading file to s3 through my API is extremely slow

Tags: file, amazon-s3, download, stream, nest

I'm utilizing my Nest API to upload files to **S3**, which is functioning smoothly. However, I'm encountering a slowdown when attempting to download files **through my API**. Are there any recommendations on how to enhance the speed of this process?

I'm currently using the Nest framework's streamable file to accomplish this. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
     async download(key: string): Promise<Readable> {
      const client = new S3Client({
        credentials: {
          accessKeyId: this.accessKeyId,
          secretAccessKey: this.secretAccessKey,
          
        },
        region: this.region,
        
      });
      const command = new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: this.bucket,
        Key: key,
      });
      try {
        const response = await client.send(command);
        const body = response.Body as Readable;
        // The Body object also has 'transformToByteArray' and 'transformToWebStream' methods.
        return body
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
  }
```

and here is my controller

```
@Controller('')
export class Download {
  constructor(@Inject(STORAGE) private _storageService: StorageServiceInterface) {}

  @Get('v1/api/download/:filename*')
  async download(@Param('filename') filename: string) {
    const file: File = await this._storageService.download(filename);
    console.log("returning stream")
    return new StreamableFile(file.stream, {
      type: 'application/pdf',
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: 'encountering a slowdown' - can you please expand on this? is it slower than downloading the object via the console? what are you comparing it against?

Comment: A 5MB file takes approximately 50 seconds to download, as opposed to downloading it from my server, which only takes about 0.5 to 1 second for the same file.

Comment: Is your server located in AWS? If so that download would never leave the AWS network and of course be very fast. Can you compare the speed between downloading the file locally using the aws cli and using your api to make sure the network is not the culprit?

Comment: @lennart independently of the OP, our team tested this on server directly, within VPC, still NestJS has much slower S3 download than simple nodejs function.

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of downloading the file to client from S3 through your API? There is pre-signed URLs for such. Like so:

1. UI calls your API to get pre-signed URL to object on S3
2. UI calls pre-signed URL to download object from S3 directly

Speed can be increased in couple places:

1. Do not stream data through your API, use download directly from S3 with pre-signed URLs
2. Take a note at which region S3 bucket is located, maybe it's on different part of the world from the user
3. You can use accelerated mode for S3 which adds something like CDN on top of S3. Your user will use closest aws edge location to stream data from S3 to them
4. If files are public consider adding actual CDN and pre-cache data on edge next to user (cloudfront)

By the way, you can upload and download to/from S3 directly with pre-signed URLs, which is the way to do it if upload/download is needed for public user.

Sample for pre-signed URLs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html

Consider to read through this official guide for performance. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance.html

Comment: Thanks but question is about downloading on server. Such use case is when server need to process data and cache the result.

Comment: @justdvl not sure about setup but hopefully what you mean is not what you should use CDN for. In any case, download probably will be fastest over HTTP GET call. If your server is EC2 or lambda running in aws it's role should have access to object and you would get it over `https://your-bucket.s3......` or with presigned url. If you want to download multiple times same thing, presigned will be faster while it's already pre-authorized. Also make sure regions match and object is near your server or at least enable transfer acceleration or setup cdn.